# Regular Expression matching RANGE of HH:MM:SS

Tags: regex, range, jflex

So I am trying to find a smart way of writing down how to recognise this particular range of time:

> HOUR: an hour with the formats HH:MM or HH:MM:SS and values between
>   08:31:12 and 23:21:10   (correct examples are: 08:31, 23:21:09,
>   12:54:51)

Do I really have to do through all the possibilities like
(08":"31)(":"(1[2-9])|([3-5][0-9]) )? |
(08":"3[2-9])(":" [0-5][0-9] )? | and so on... (pretty long)

Is there a smarter way to handle particular ranges like this example?
Thanks guys

Comment: Smart way here consists in not using a regex :) Parse it and check with available DateTime methods.

Comment: @stribizhev you mean I should parse a normal hour like a canonical
hour = [0-2][0-9]":"[0-5][0-9](":"[0-5][0-9])? 
and then after in the parser everytime I retrieve a token hour I check if it is in the range I need? And if it's not?

Comment: You can use [`\b\d{2}(?::\d{2}){1,2}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/nG7pK5/1) and then parse the value obtained.